# Match Question mark at the beginning of a regular expression for .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to match a regex expression `?page` in url http://mydomain.com/?page in .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^([\?])page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\\?])page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\?)page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\\?)page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^\?page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^\\?page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
```

For the life of me none of these work.

Simply put, how do I match the question mark regex in .htaccess?

Answer (score 4):

The match in `RewriteRule` only matches against the URI, **not the query string**. In order to match against the query string, you need to use a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page$
RewriteRule ^ /?menyu=404 [L]
```

Note that the %{QUERY_STRING} variable doens't include the leading **?**.

Comment: Works like a person in a Apple factory. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to remove the hard anchor to start-of-input `^`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*\?page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
```

Or if you want to restrict it to that particular domain:

```
RewriteRule ^mydomain.com\?page$ ?menyu=404 [L]
```

The regex for a literal question mark is `\?`
In a character class, no need to escape anything (except `]`), so `[?]` would also work.

Comment: `RewriteRule` won't match against the query string.